# Fixed video capture orientation for RTCMTLVideoView webrtc

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc

I have an iOS app that only supports portrait when rotating the device the video captured by the RTCMTLVideoView rotates to landscape orientation, even when the rest of the UI stays in portrait.

So far the only solution that I found is to listen for the **UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification** notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
```

and disabling it

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"orientation changed");
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and keep it locked to portrait without this ugly workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in my case was that the video captured with the front camera was no mirrored.

I fixed the issue flipping the RTCMTLVideoView

`self.myRTCMTLVideoView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0)`

Comment: Have you solved the orientation issue? I have used CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0) but this is not helpful when orientation is changed to Landscape.

Comment: Does anyone know orientation change for landscape mode?

Comment: This is fixing the front camera mirroring (flip) issue for WebRTC on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer assumes usage of the latest stable [M70](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/6ImvPjWQvbE/AlCtGQnYBQAJ) branch of WebRTC at the moment, as it's a moving target and API of its internal classes changes frequently.

---

Looks like `RTCMTLVideoView` is still work in progress and doesn't handle all scenarios appropriately. It has a [`rotationOverride`](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/branch-heads/70/sdk/objc/Framework/Headers/WebRTC/RTCMTLVideoView.h#47) property, but no documentation or example on how to use it. There is a similar [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/RTCMTLVideoView%7Csort:date/discuss-webrtc/NiagV5qRaKg/FO75xFuvAAAJ) on Google Groups, which hasn't yet received attention, I encourage you to participate in discussion there, so WebRTC developers would know about that issue relevancy and made actions to fix it.

In the meantime, I suggest to switch to `RTCEAGLVideoView` which should work fine in that case.